# Save file to specific folder with curl command

Tags: bash, shell, curl, directory

In a shell script, I want to download a file from some URL and save it to a specific folder. What is the specific CLI flag I should use to download files to a specific folder with the `curl` command, or how else do I get that result?

Comment: simply wrap a curl with 2 extra commands: `pushd <path>; curl ...; popd;`

Answer (score 427, accepted):

I don't think you can give a path to curl, but you can CD to the location, download and CD back.

```
cd target/path && { curl -O URL ; cd -; }
```

Or using subshell.

```
(cd target/path && curl -O URL)
```

Both ways will only download if path exists. `-O` keeps remote file name. After download it will return to original location.

If you need to set filename explicitly, you can use small `-o` option:

```
curl -o target/path/filename URL
```

Comment: I have this command: curl -LOk `basename /packages` "http://github.com/ziyaddin/xampp/archive/master.zip". But it says that wrong filename --> `basename /packages`

Comment: You can also use a subshell, like so: `(cd target/path; curl -O URL)`

Comment: What is the difference between the two? The first one cd's into a the directory and downloads the file, then cds out. The second stays in current directory and curls file to specificed location. Second one seems more simple.

Comment: @HenryZhu In the first one the filename is derived from the name of the file on the server. In the second you are renaming the content you downloaded to a name you provide.

Comment: I would really like an option to specify a directory, but use the server's filename. It seems like using `cd` is the best option currently, though it seems slightly inelegant.

Comment: If you are in a script, you can do something like:
`for url in $(cat urllistFile ) ;    do         name=$(basename $url) ; curl -o [yourDir]/$name $url ;  done`

Answer (score 111):

The `--output-dir` option is available since [curl 7.73.0](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2020/09/10/store-the-curl-output-over-there/):

```
curl --create-dirs -O --output-dir /tmp/receipes https://example.com/pancakes.jpg
```

Comment: unfortunately,
those options aren't available for Ubuntu since version 7.73.0 is not intended yet for ubuntu :(

Comment: Although still doesn't work on Ubuntu- curl version is sadly 7.68.0 for 20.04 LTS- I can confirm it works on OSX Monterey, so worthy of an upvote

Comment: On Ubuntu Server 20.04 - for `curl` _7.68.0_ exists `--create-dirs` but does **not** exist `--output-dir`

Comment: works on windows too

Comment: it works well on Ubuntu 22.04 with curl 7.81.0

Answer (score 28):

`curl` doesn't have an option to that (without also specifying the filename), but `wget` does. The directory can be relative or absolute. Also, the directory will automatically be created if it doesn't exist.

```
wget -P relative/dir "$url"

wget -P /absolute/dir "$url"
```

Answer (score 12):

it works for me:

```
curl http://centos.mirror.constant.com/8-stream/isos/aarch64/CentOS-Stream-8-aarch64-20210916-boot.iso --output ~/Downloads/centos.iso
```

where:

`--output` allows me to set up the path and the naming of the file and extension file that I want to place.

Answer (score 9):

## Use redirection:

This works to drop a `curl` downloaded file into a specified path:

```
curl https://download.test.com/test.zip > /tmp/test.zip
```

Obviously "*test.zip*" is whatever arbitrary name you want to label the redirected file- could be the same name or a different name.

I actually prefer @oderibas solution, but this will get you around the issue until your distro supports curl version 7.73.0 or later-

Answer (score 5):

For powershell in Windows, you can add *relative path* + *filename* to `--output` flag:

```
curl -L  http://github.com/GorvGoyl/Notion-Boost-browser-extension/archive/master.zip --output build_firefox/master-repo.zip
```

here *build_firefox* is relative folder.

Answer (score 2):

**Use wget**

```
wget -P /your/absolut/path "https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.3.3.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Batch to create a safe filename from a URL and save it to a folder named **tmp/**. I do think it's strange that this isn't an option on the Windows or Linux Curl versions.

```
@echo off
set url=%1%

for /r %%f in (%url%) do (
    set url=%%~nxf.txt
    curl --create-dirs -L -v -o tmp/%%~nxf.txt %url%
)
```

The above Batch file will take a single input, a URL, and create a filename from the url. If no filename is specified it will be saved as **tmp/.txt**. So it's not all done for you but it gets the job done in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, in PowerShell, `curl` is an alias of the cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` and this syntax works:

```sh
curl "url" -OutFile file_name.ext
```

For instance:

```sh
curl "https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/docker-compose.yaml" -OutFile docker-compose.yaml
```

Source: https://krypted.com/windows-server/its-not-wget-or-curl-its-iwr-in-windows/