# Curl POST upload file test

Tags: api, unit-testing, curl

I have a FastAPI with the following type:

```
@app.post("/extract_text") 
async def create_upload_file(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return FileResponse(path="Outputs/ocr_output.zip", filename="{}".format(main.allinall(upload_file))+"_output.zip", media_type='application/zip')
```

In browser and with the help of UI that I have, I am able to upoad files and download the output file (return...).

I want to test this on a linux service and I have to test this api through a curl command. I am using this command:

```
 curl -X 'POST' 'http://localhost/extract_text' -H 'accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F 'file=@demo2_test_imageinput.png;type=application/json'
```

and here is the error I receive:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","upload_file"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

input is a png file avaialble in the current folder and output would be a zipfile as the output of allinall function.

when I try this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "data=@demo2_test_imageinput.png" http://localhost/extract_text
```

I receive this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Server: nginx/1.15.12
Date: Thu, 19 May 2022 20:16:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 95
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you are getting it wrong.

```
file=@demo2_test_imageinput.png
```

As per your function def, your multipart field name should be `upload_file`

`async def create_upload_file(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...))`

So your curl request must have the parameter

`upload_file=@demo2_test_imageinput.png`

Comment: Thanks John! it worked. Just one question, the output of this is a file which will be downloaded on browser but in CMD, I just see not meaningful information showing. Is there a way to have the output as a file downloaded instead of the not meaningfull info?

Comment: Or even saving the output file in OUTPUTS folder would be ideal.

Comment: Could this be what you are looking for?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362402/save-file-to-specific-folder-with-curl-command